# Need help to integrate SSRS 2016 Reports in Java Web Application

Tags: java, sql-server, reporting-services

We are migrating `SQL Server` from `2008R2` to `2016`. We used `exe` file to access `SSRS` reports using `ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl` file.

After the migration we are getting the following error while trying to read the report using `C#.net` program.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at getMaPSStartpage.ReportService2008.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at getMaPSStartpage.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Thanks!!
Raja Sekhar

Comment: Is the SSRS server standalone or did that get upgraded as well?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS web service is returning an error message and that error is in the form of text/html. Most likely it's a permissions issue. However, you can use fiddler to capture the entire HTML contents and see the exact error message.

First, try navigating to the SSRS report service URL in a browser. Normally it's `http://<reportservername>/reportserver`. Then execute one of the reports. If that's successful then it could be your C# application running under a less privileged account.